# WSO2 Data Services Server on Linux 64-bit?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm trying to get WSO2 DSS installed on a 64-bit server and am getting the following error:

> /opt/wso2dss/bin/daemon.sh:
>   /opt/wso2dss/./bin/native/wrapper-linux-x86-32: /lib/ld-linux.so.2:
>   bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up changing:

```
$DSS_HOME/bin/native/wrapper-linux-x86-32
```

to:

```
$DSS_HOME/bin/native/wrapper-linux-x86-32.bak
```

Then I was able to start it up using the daemon as normal.  It looks like it was defaulting to the wrapper-linux-x86-32 for some reason even though I'm on x64.

Comment: In my Oracle Linux 6.2 64 bits distribution the name of wrapper that I needed was 'wrapper-linux-x86-64'

Answer (score 0):

What is the operating system that you are using. Looks like some thing related to wrapper. 
In case you are on linux env, you may use nohup instead of the wrapper.

nohup wso2server.sh start &

Comment: I'm on CentOS 6.2 x86_64.  I moved the wrapper-linux-x86-32 to wrapper-linux-x86-32.bak and was able to get the DSS started.  I didn't have that problem on my other CentOS 5.6 x86_64 host though, so I'm not quite sure why it didn't work.